# Custom module doesnt work on live

Tags: magento

I have written a custom module using catalog_product_save_after hook to save attributes programmatically in each products. Though it works on my localhost(wamp with windows) but it doesn’t work on live. I am using community edition of Magento ver. 1.4.1.1

Inside app\etc\modules, the xml file is as following ,

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
    <VP_CustomOptions>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    </VP_CustomOptions>
    </modules>
    </config>
```

And inside app\code\local\VP\CustomOptions\etc, the config.xml is as following

```
     <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
    <VP_CustomOptions>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    </VP_CustomOptions>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <events>
    <catalog_product_save_after>
    <observers>
    <custom_options>
    <type>singleton</type>
    <class>VP_CustomOptions_Model_Observer</class>
    <method>Add_CustomOptions_Automatically</method>
    </custom_options>
    </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
    </global>
    </config>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is never a good problem description. What happens exactly, what goes wrong? What errors do you get?

Comment: It doesn't triggered the event. I have put die on the model class to check whether event is triggering or not and it didn't.And there is no error too.The Compiler Status is also disabled and i tried with even by clearing cache.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue. It was due to the name of the model directory. I used small case on Windows as

```
/app/code/local/VP/CustomOptions/model
```

And when I changed the model folder to capital on linux, it works. I have changed the model folder name as following

```
/app/code/local/VP/CustomOptions/Model
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone else will probably be able to weigh in on exactly why, but module names should have one capital letter for each part (separated by _). Try renaming your module to Vp_Customoptions. (Part of the reason is because Magento uses the names to automatically find classes). Also rename your directories to Vp/Customoptions etc.

Windows is case insensitive to file and directory names so it works fine there, but Linux and others are case sensitive. Hence it fails.